# Remove element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to replace `<span class="st">&#185;</span>` (entire value) with no value.

How can I do in XSLT?

Comment: Show us first, how did you try?  You can do it with a template for example.

Comment: <xsl:when test="contains(.,'value to replace')">
             <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,' value to replace.','')"/>
        </xsl:when>

Comment: it contains class="st" which don't know how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the identify transformation plus a null override for the element that you wish to remove:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="span[@class='st'][.='&#185;']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Ok, the issue is like I have 
<description>
               <markup:rich-text xmlns:markup="http://www.webcollage.com/objects/2008/1/markup">
The sleek and slim OneRemote automatically detects and controls all compatible connected devices and content.<span class="st">&#185;</span>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <i>* Remote color and design may vary by model.<i/>
                     <br/>
                  </i>
               </markup:rich-text>
            </description>

And I want to remove "<span class="st">&#185;</span>" will above code work?

Comment: Yes, it will work with that document.  (Next time, however, you should include sample input, expected output, and a tried solution in your question per [ask].  Thanks.)